How can a rollup use multiple Data Availability layers?
From Optimism's docs:

The Data Availability Layer defines where the raw inputs to an OP Stack based chain are published. An OP Stack chain can use one or more Data Availability module to source its input data. Because an OP Stack chain is derived from the Data Availability Layer, the Data Availability module(s) used have a significant impact on the security model of a system.

My question is: How would this work in practice? Would the data posted to both DA layers, using one of them as a backup? Or would it posted to just one layer at a time?
